# cakephp insert and update

Tags: php, sql, insert, cakephp-2.0

this is my table

```
protected $_schema = array(
    'id'        => array(
        'type'      => 'bigint',
        'length'    => 20,
        'null'      => false
    ),
    'import_id'     => array(
        'type'      => 'bigint',
        'length'    => 255,
        'null'      => false
    ),
    'betsapi_id'    => array(
        'type'      => 'string',
        'length'    => 100,
        'null'      => false
    ),
    'name'      => array(
        'type'      => 'string',
        'length'    => 255,
        'null'      => true
    ),
    'status'    => array(
        'type'      => 'int',
        'length'    => 1,
        'null'      => false
    ),
    'type'      => array(
        'type'      => 'int',
        'length'    => 1,
        'null'      => false
    ),
    'duration'      => array(
        'type'      => 'int',
        'length'    => 1,
        'null'      => false
    ),
    'date'      => array(
        'type'      => 'string',
        'length'    => null,
        'null'      => true
    ),
    'last_update'      => array(
        'type'      => 'string',
        'length'    => null,
        'null'      => true
    ),
    'result'    => array(
        'type'      => 'string',
        'length'    => 20,
        'null'      => false
    ),
    'active'    => array(
        'type'      => 'tinyint',
        'length'    => 1,
        'null'      => true
    ),
    'league_id' => array(
        'type'      => 'int',
        'length'    => 11,
        'null'      => true
    ),
    'feed_type' => array(
        'type'      => 'string',
        'length'    => 10,
        'null'      => false
    ),

);
```

and this is my save function

```
 public function saveEvent
(
    $eventId = null,
    $importId = null,
    $betsapi_id=null,
    $eventName,
    $status = self::EVENT_STATUS_NOT_STARTED,
    $type = self::EVENT_TYPE_PREMATCH,
    $duration = null,
    $startDate,
    $lastUpdate = null,
    $eventResult = null,
    $eventState = self::EVENT_ACTIVE_STATE,
    $leagueId,
    $feedType
)
{
    $this->create();
    $data = array(
        'import_id'     =>  $importId,
        'betsapi_id'    =>  $betsapi_id,
        'name'          =>  $eventName,
        'status'        =>  $status,
        'type'          =>  $type,
        'duration'      =>  $duration,
        'date'          =>  $startDate,
        'last_update'   =>  $lastUpdate,
        'result'        =>  $eventResult,
        'active'        =>  $eventState,
        'league_id'     =>  $leagueId,
        'feed_type'     =>  $feedType
    );

    if (!is_null($eventId)) {
        $this->id = $eventId;
    }

    if (is_null($importId)) {
        unset($data['import_id']);
    }

    if ($this->hasAny(array("Event.id" => $eventId))){
        unset($data["active"]); // in case admin has disabled this event, do not update this field.
    }var_dump($data);
    $this->save($data);

    print $this->id;exit;
}
```

vardump befor insert

```
array(12) {
```

["import_id"]=>
string(7) "2545008"
["betsapi_id"]=>
string(8) "97525420"
["name"]=>
string(22) "Premier League 2020-21"
["status"]=>
int(0)
["type"]=>
int(1)
["duration"]=>
NULL
["date"]=>
string(19) "2021-05-16 14:00:00"
["last_update"]=>
string(19) "2020-08-16 12:26:26"
["result"]=>
string(0) ""
["active"]=>
int(1)
["league_id"]=>
string(1) "2"
["feed_type"]=>
string(8) "Betclick"
}

all filed save successfully expect betsapi_id
what wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi pashmak mirza / how are u ?
your sending key  betsapi_id have a value! what is your problem ?
["betsapi_id"]=> string(8) "97525420"